# Global Variables from WinForm

Tags: function, powershell, user-interface, global-variables

I am currently trying to use the values of a date/time picker variable from one function and use it multiple times in another function. The date/time picker is on a form, so when a user sets a start date and end date, those values are assigned to a variable to use in the other function, which should call both those variables at least twice. While trying to call that variable from the first function, it contains a null value even though it was assigned to a variable. I am trying to keep the value that was created in one function to use in another function multiple times. Thank you.

```
 Set-strictMode -off
    [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms")
    [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = "tls12, tls11, tls"

   $global:startDate=$null
$global:endDate=$null

function MakeForm{

#region begin GUI
$Form                            = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.ClientSize                 = '396,180'
$Form.text                       = "Rexpii Integrations Version (Beta)"
$Form.BackColor                  = "#ffffff"
$Form.TopMost                    = $False
$Form.Icon= [System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon('C:\files\scripts\tpgicon.ico')

$btnSubmit                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$btnSubmit.text                    = "Submit"
$btnSubmit.width                   = 60
$btnSubmit.height                  = 30
$btnSubmit.location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(220,116)
$btnSubmit.Font                    = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'
$btnSubmit.Add_Click({
    $global:startDate= $Global:txtStartDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
                  $global:endDate= $Global:txtEndDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

             GetData
             $Form.Close()})

$btnCancel                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$btnCancel.text                    = "Cancel"
$btnCancel.width                   = 60
$btnCancel.height                  = 30
$btnCancel.location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(288,116)
$btnCancel.Font                    = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'
$btnCancel.Add_Click({
            $Form.Close()
                })
$Global:txtStartDate                       = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker
$Global:txtStartDate.width                 = 150
$Global:txtStartDate.location              = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(208,40)
$Global:txtStartDate.Format = "Custom"
$Global:txtstartDate.CustomFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"


$Global:txtEndDate                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker
$Global:txtEndDate.width                   = 150
$Global:txtEndDate.location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(208,80)
$Global:txtEndDate.Format="Custom"
$Global:txtEndDate.CustomFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
$Form.controls.AddRange(@($btnSubmit,$btnCancel,$PictureBox1,$PictureBox2,$StartDate,$EndDate,$lblStartDate,$lblEndDate,$txtStartDate, $txtEndDate))

[void]$Form.ShowDialog()

}

MakeForm

function GetData{ 
#my scripts number one
Write-Output "This is the first $global:startDate to $global:endDate example"

#my scripts number two
Write-Output "This is the second $global:startDate to $global:endDate example"

}
```

Comment: I took out much of what I had and only focused on the problematic code. But, now I have edited it to include EVERYTHING. I just assumed that I wouldn't need to provide the more obvious stuff. Sorry.

Comment: And I've already stated what issue I am having. I know this might be difficult to figure out, but please read what I have provided as the issue.

Comment: Well my first suggestion would be to use `$GLOBAL:startDate` and `$GLOBAL:endDate` everywhere instead of `$env:startDate` and `$env:endDate` as you do in some places.

Comment: I have done that. I accidentally posted the code that I am currently working that suggested creating an $env instead of a $global or $script. I re-edited with the correct (but wrong) code, which is the original one I am having trouble with.

Comment: Please, please, please create a [MCVE]. Often, the act of doing that shows you the issue.

Comment: I have provided the entire code. I am currently troubleshooting it while utilizing outside resources. I was in the middle of making changes (that didn't work out) when you first requested the entire code. The edits now provide the entire original code. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, the first time I provided with what I had issues with, then you requested an example followed with that same link. So, I am confused as what you're trying to ask of me, even after I've provided as much information as I can.

Comment: This is literally the fourth time I have made the changes you have requested. It is basically the first block I provided originally. I've edited it with the code that is having issues.

Comment: The first block did not have the code that was assigning the variables. Someone even created an incorrect answer because that bit was missing.

Comment: The original block did provide the variables. It just didn't include the global declaration because I only wanted to provide what I was having issues with and just assumed that the declaration was clear enough for someone with experience, but I guess I was wrong. Please address the issue.

Comment: Remove the extra {} in the OnClick handler.

Comment: Sorry, but that's not what I am having an issue with. The extra braces are there accidentally because I've had to edit and repost five times now. I removed it with my problem unchanged.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you tehn. When I copy and pasted the code that you provided and removed those braces and ran it I got `This is the first 2018-05-15 to 2018-05-31 example` and `This is the second 2018-05-15 to 2018-05-31 example` for output. I believe that is what you want to see right?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to define your functions before you can use them. You are trying to call `GetData` before it's defined. Move the call to `MakeForm` (which also shows the form) to after the function definition for `GetData`.

Second, should change `GetData` to call `Write-Host` instead of `Write-Output` so you can see the output from the event handler. And if you call `GetData` after showing the form, you'll see that the globals are set properly.

So the last part of your script should look like:

```
function GetData{ 
    #my scripts number one
    Write-Host "This is the first $global:startDate to $global:endDate example"

    #my scripts number two
    Write-Host "This is the second $global:startDate to $global:endDate example"
}

MakeForm

# Call GetData again to verify that the globals are set.
GetData
```